# Electric burner gets red hot when oven is turned on

Tags: electrical, oven

The burner switch is in the off position, but the burner is getting hot when oven is on. (This is not a case of simple heat transference from the oven) the burner is getting power to it, actually heating it up.

Note: this started happening after I replaced 2 infinite switches for both my 8" burners. The original switchs where 10-11.5 A switch. The new ones are 9-10.5 A switches and yes they are compatible. Also the burner thats getting turned on is a 6" burner. Its not one of them i worked on.

Comment: If the oven is off and you turn the burner on/off with the switch, does it work correctly?

Comment: What make and model of range are we dealing with here?

Comment: It obviously relates to the switch replacement work you did. Were more than 2 wires involved per switch?  You jumbled them up. Go back to the schematic and work the problem.

Comment: If you mean the surface range burners get red hot when the oven is on , they are hooked up incorrectly.

Comment: To me it sounds like you mixed up an L with an h terminal. If a 4or 5 wire switch, what is the stove brand and model?  Not all switches have the terminals in the same positions. Some controls are 240v and some are 120. It’s easy to mix up the 240v models terminals up.

Comment: All 4 burners work as intended when the oven is off. The make and model is "whirlpool Mo: 3148954". Its not related to what I did, as I mentioned already, all I did was unplug the unit, pulled the wire harness off the old switch to the 8" burner, and plugged it into the new switch. (Can only be plugged in 1 way) then I finished mounting the switch with 2 screws. I never touched the switch to the 6" burner or its wire harness. Yet that 6" burner is now the problem child. The oven is a 240v unit with the proper 9-10.5 A 240v switch

Comment: The main control module also gave out on this stove just before the two 8" switches failed. I replaced that about a month before the switches. And now I'm having mysterious heating issues with the oven turn on a burner. I'm inclined to think the switches to the 6" burners need replacing also. I just don't understand the how the switch could be the culprit in a situation like this. The main control module seams more plausible to me. But even that doesn't have control over the power being sent past the physical connections in the switch.

Comment: We need the model number of the range, not the burner switch. The number you gave is a standard infinite surface burner which has ALL of its input power and load terminals disconnected in the OFF position, so couldn't possibly have any bearing on your problem, which almost certainly is due to miswiring elsewhere.